# Interpreting residual plots from a regression problem using CNNs on image data

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

My dataset consists of 799 images and each image is associated with a real number. I have split my dataset into 3 parts (80-10-10 split) randomly. I have trained my model using split1. The values follow a gaussian distribution.

I have trained an CNN model to output a real when an image is fed to it. These are my $R^2$ values and Residual plots for each of the dataset split.

**Split1:**

$R^2$ = $0.9857076788979228$

Residual plot:

[image]

**Split2:**

$R^2$ = 0.7396153728584336

Residual plot:

[image]

**Split3:**

$R^2$ = 0.7290908907070102

Residual plot:

[image]

I can see that my model is biased, probably overfitting ( high $R^2$ value  on **Split1**). I don't understand why the $R^2$ values of **Split2** and **Split3** are nearly same and the Residual plots look similar.

What is the next step for me ? Should I reduce model complexity ?

Comment: You may also want to post this question over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: I have already posted there, I'm in a bit of a hurry. To reach an even larger group of people, I have posted here.